# Grails performance issue

Tags: performance, grails, groovy

During request processing i need to load a lot of entities (of two kinds). Maybe 4 or 5 thousands. Most of them are served from 2nd-level cache. The problem is *dependency injection* which is applied to every domain class killing application performance.

Profiler shows bottleneck is **org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.ControllersDomainBindingApi.autowire** which calls **GrailsMetaClassUtils.invokeMethodIfExists**.

I tried to load entities from *Controller* and from *Service* classes. Results are the same.

Is it possible to disable this unnecessary **DI** feature for particular case or class?

My Grails version is **2.3.11**.

Java **1.8**

Comment: What do you need to do to all those entities? Maybe a good-performing query can be devised?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use explicitly lazy fetching or batch fetching? You can check examples and further explanations on [official docs](http://docs.grails.org/2.3.11/guide/single.html#fetching).

btw it is usually better to store in memory just ids of such a big sets and load them one-by-one when handling them (to avoid possible inconsistency which may occur between obtaining objects and handling them)

Comment: Yep, i use lazy batch fetching and load them one-by-one using _Entity.load(id)_. The problem is Hibernate stores entities in cache in deserialized form, so every cache retrieval requires entity object instantiation. And each instantiation performs autowiring which consumes a lot of CPU.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable dependency injection in newer versions of Grails with the following configuration in `grails-app/conf/runtime.groovy` (for Grails 3) or `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy` (for Grails 2 using GORM 5/6):

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
     autowire false
}
```

Comment: I'm digging to the metaclass modification, but can't make it work. My constructor is just skipped. Can you give a proper way of doing that? Thanks!